# Map Json data to an object using AJAX and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, ajax

how can I use the Json formatted data sent by an AJAX request in C#?

Here's the View with the JQuery and AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnGet").click(function () {
            var values =
                {  
                    "Name": "Manuel Andrade",
                    "DateOfBirth": "12/01/1995"
                }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/WebApi/GetAge",
                data: values,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Hello: " + response.Name + ".\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the Controller:

```
 public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/WebApi/GetAge")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public Person GetAge(Person person)
    {
        //person = new Person();
        //person.Name = "Luis";

        JsonTest(person);


        //int ageInMonths = calculateAgeInMonths(person);
        //int ageInYears = calculateAgeInYears(person);

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ageInMonths);
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ageInYears);

        return person;
       }
    }
```

The Person Model has exactly the same attributes as the Json variable in the view. Shouldn't it create an object automatically? The method JsonTest() works properly, it is used to serialize the data. If I uncomment the person instantiation and assignation to Luis the method does return a Json with that data to the view. But if I try to use the person parameter just like that it throws a null Exception. How can I pass the var values in the View to the GetAge method so I can assign it to an object?

Comment: which framework and which version is this?

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me when I removed the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` line.

It isn't returned as application/json by default.